# ! operator in do while loop

Tags: c, do-while, insertion-sort

I'm just doing a tutorial on insertion sorting in C, and I'm struggling to understand the way the ! operator is used as the condition for a do while loop.

The condition is just `while (!done)` but I don't understand how it knows *what* is not supposed to be equal to the variable done. Something like `while (done==0)` would make more sense to me.

I'm only just starting to code so sorry if the answer is really obvious! I tried googling it but I found it hard to express the problem...

The code is as follows:

```
void insertionSortArray (int arr[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        int value = arr[i];
        int j = i -1;
        int done = 0;
        do
        {
            if (arr[j]>value)
            {
                arr [j+1] = arr[j];
                j - -;
                if (j<0)
                done = 1;
            }

            else
                done = 1;

        } while (!done);

        arr [j+1] = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `!` is the negation, or "not" operator. So read it out loud: do <this> while not done.

Comment: but done is just a variable that's either equal to 1 or 0.. what is it that has to not be equal to that variable?

Comment: @TessaGrafen: cf my answer, `0` as a value is treated as  `false` in C. All non-zero values are true. `!` negates the value, so `while (!done)` translates to `while not done`, and because `done` starts out as `0` (ie `false`), the loop carries on until `done` is assigned a non-zero value (replace `done = 1 ` with `done = 123;` or `done = -123`, and the results will be exactly the same

Comment: "While not done" and "while done is zero" is the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're exactly the same thing. `!done` and `done == 0` are interchangeable. The thing about C is: it didn't have a *"true"* boolean type for a long time. Booleans were only introduced in C99.

All zero values are considered false, other values are true. that's why `!done` is true, for as long as `done == 0` (`done` is 0 -> false, `!false` -> `true`). `!` is the logical *NOT* operator, as always, and does what it does: negates whatever comes after. Therefore `done = 0` => `done` is false, `!done` -> the opposite of false, being true.

If you find `done == 0` easier to read, then by all means write it like that. Although, it is more common to see the shorter version.

False/true checks that are *Very* common:

```
type *foo = malloc(123 * sizeof *foo);
if (!foo)
    exit(1); // failed to alloc memory

void my_function(int *ptr, size_t size)
{
    if (!ptr)
        return; // a NULL pointer was passed
    // ...
}
```

### TL;DR

Because both statements are interchangeable, write what you find makes the most sense. Perhaps reading both statements aloud (although it may seem silly) will make you change your mind:

```
while done equals zero
//vs
while not done
```

Which of the two sentences makes most sense now?

Comment: There is a chance that an older compiler might compile faster code for != rather than ==.  Usually this only affects  float and doubles.